# Do the people/the church know about Tenebrarum?

Tags: savage-worlds, lore, necropolis-2350

Do the people living on Necropolis know about the spirit/demon Tenebrarum, who brought the Rephaim into the world? In one or two missions from the campaign that is included in the book, the *Ordo Tenebrarum* is explicitly mentioned regarding the so called *dark knights*. I am wondering: do the people / the church simply know the name that this cult gave itself, or do they actually know about Tenebrarum itself?

I read the whole book, and it does not say anything except that there are many things the church does not know about, like some sort of Rephaim. I also had a look at the 2351-2355 Expansion that is released, which does not clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to go straight to the source and e-mail Paul "Wiggy" Wilson, who is the author of *Necropolis 2350*. Here was his response:

> I'm guessing by "the spirit/demon Tenebrarum" they mean The Dark? I don't recall ever giving it another name. Anyway, no, the Church is ignorant of its existence.

I gather that if the Church is ignorant, the general public is ignorant as well.

Comment: If there was some miscommunication about the demon being referred to, let me know and I'll send a followup question to Wiggy.

Comment: Well, in the german version He is called tenebrarum, as far as I recall. Thank you, this is what I guessed ;)